# Regular Expression for String-Number Combination

Tags: regex

I need an regular expression for RR-1000 i.e First two digits must be alphabets and it must be followed by an '-'(hyphen) then there must be four numbers .The total length should not be greater than 7 digits.

Comment: digits != alphabets. Anyway, any attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
([A-Za-z]{2})[-](\d{4})
```

You can see it as follows:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: You don't even need the parentheses or brackets; `[A-z]{2}-\d{4}` should work fine.

Comment: @AndrewArnold A few languages define `-` differently. Since I primarily work in Lua, the `-` means a lazy match. And hence, my practice of enclosing it as `[-]`

Comment: True, it depends on language. My answer is valid in Javascript, at the very least.

Comment: I'm curious as to what language defines `-` differently.

Comment: @Jerry http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html Search the following on the page: "Patterns in Lua offer four modifiers"

Comment: I wouldn't call it regex, but more like a Lua expression if you ask me xP And if you did write a Lua pattern, you'd have to use `%a%a%-%d%d%d%d` instead of what you have used above.

Comment: @Jerry of course; but I've been writing lua patterns for so long that `[-]` is just muscle memory :P

Comment: Lol, ok. Though your regex isn't entirely correct. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18661919/1578604).